# how to add a flash message in the ajax success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

hi I am working with symfony , and sometimes I need to work with ajax to avoid the reloading of the page . I have two entities , "event" and "list" and I want to associate some lists to an event , my code wotk correctly with ajax , but after recording I want to show a flash message that makes the user understand that the operation is finished.
here my jquery code:

```html
 <script type="application/javascript">
          $(".modal-body").hide();
        $("#btnenr").click(function(){

  var ev = {{id}};
  console.log(ev);
  var liste = $("input:checked").map(function () { return this.value; }).get();
  if (typeof liste !== 'undefined' && liste.length > 0) {
   
       $(".modal-body").show();
        $.ajax({
             type: 'get',
             url: '{{ path('liste_enregisterEvListe') }}',
             data : {
                        arrayy: liste,
                        x: ev
                    }, 
              success: function(data) {
              $(".modal-body").hide();
                // code that display the flash message
             }
            });

            }
       else{
       alert('Vous n \'avez rien saisi');
   
      }
       }
       
     
  );
    
        </script>
```

and in my twig I have a division of flash messag:

```html
<div class="page-content">
            {% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.get('notice') %}
                <div class="note note-warnning">
                    <p>{{ flash_message }}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.get('success') %}
                <div class="note note-success">
                    <p>{{ flash_message }}</p>
                </div>
```

so how can I add the flash message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the Flashmessage inside the Symfony Controller. Example: [Flash-Message](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html#flash-messages)

```
$session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Message Text');
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you don't have to use any flash message here. They're designed to be displayed once when the page is reloaded.
Just display a notification the way you like it (using something like https://notifyjs.com/ maybe ?) in the success callaback.